# how to get summary of value | Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to get the summary of column value and I using laravel how can I do it.

> the column is price column

I want the total of the price

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#aggregates

Comment: can you update the question .. with some codes

Comment: I want get the total price how I can get it

Comment: show me your code may be then I can help you..

Comment: You have to submit more information about table schema, some code, column where you want to aggregate value, Post enough information so the people can understand what actually you are asking. No body can suggest you anything from this piece of text you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need sth like:

```
$summary = DB::table('your_table')->sum('price');
```

More info you will find here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#aggregates